# android market download statistics dwarfing google analytics numbers

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, google-play

I got an application that on http://market.android.com/publish/ shows around 20k active installs / 30k total installs. However, google analytics for the app (that's not really doing anything weird. It's just using the normal api, collecting fairly standard data). Is showing 100k+ unique visitors since launch (around 37k so far this month).

What should I trust? How can I find out what's right and whats wrong?

Comment: are you comparing apples to apples? I don't really know much of that android thing but "active installs" does not sound like it would be the same/equivalent metric as "unique visitors"...I mean it 'sounds' like if you were to for instance compare unique visitors to registered members on a site. Those numbers wouldn't match up unless you had a 100% registration rate

Comment: Market gives both active installs and total installs. And when analytics has "unique users" on 120k, and google market says 30k people have installed the app something is wrong. I EXTREMELY seriously doubt  I've got 100k people downloading it from alternative sources.

Comment: What is used to determine 'unique visitors'? If it's IP address and the same user's IP changes - they will appear as two unique users.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're comparing apples & oranges here? The google market numbers are unique installs. One install can lead to a very high number of visits, for instance somebody installed your app right after you launched it and visited it every day (or even multiple times per day). This will all count as "1" for the market stats and as very many for analytics.
You can select the Advanced Segment "new visitors" in analytics and this should be much more comparable.

Another explanation can be that you or someone else published your APK on an alternative market or just somewhere on the internet, and people who get it from there are tracked by analytics but of course not by the market numbers.

Comment: See the comments on the original question, I sortof doubt it's that far off.